# Character armature arm bends in a curve instead of 90 degree angle?

Tags: animation, rigging, 3d-view, armature, pose-mode

I'm trying to make my characters arm bend properly, but I noticed that it slightly moves downwards then curves at the elbow joint.

Here's the arm at normal view

[image]

Then when I bend, the elbow drops below the resting axis and then curves as well. Is this normal?

[image]

This is the normal weight paint, but I tried to paint over it yet it didn't fix the arm dropping below the resting axis.

[image]

Do I need more loop cuts?

[image]

I want something like this where it is perfectly straight and not curving like in my example above

[image]

Comment: please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: with what method did you parent your armature to your arm?

Comment: you could easily fix it with removing some edge loops but you probably need to correct the weight, as the lower arm bone seems to influence the upper arm vertices and vice versa

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a "normal" subdivided cylinder

[image]

then parent an armature with automatic weight to it

you will get:

[image]

[image]

and it bends like this:

[image]

Comment: but thats when it's a solo arm, but what if its atttached to a mesh that you created and made the arm by extruding out from the sides?

Comment: it is exactly the same. As moonboots said - provide your blend file, so we can help you. Everything else is just "guessing".